# Is there a way to trigger a function after the browser renders a certain element?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have the following simple markup:

```
<div ng-class="getClass(currentElement)" ng-click="doSomething(currentElement)"> {{currentElement.someValue}} </div>
```

Is there a way to run a function every time this markup is changed due currentElement changing? (and NOT when currentElement.someValue changes)

Comment: May be its possible by assign a ID to particular element and check its attributes for change !!

Comment: You may consider other methods in the [scope API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) such as `$scope.watch` and `$scooe.on`. Read the docs and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd rather not fiddle with constructed Ids because it gets really confusing really fast.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I'd rather not use $scope.watch because I want to use it in more than one case and I'd rather not have a lot of watched variable for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$scope.watch`? According to [the angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

> `$rootScope.Scope#$watch(watchExpression, [listener],
>   [objectEquality]);`
>
> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the
>   watchExpression changes.

Or you may try to control the events yourself with `$scope.on` and $scope.emit`.

> `$rootScope.Scope#$on(name, listener);`
>
> Listens on events of a given type. See $emit for discussion of event
>   life cycle.
>
> `$rootScope.Scope#$emit(name, args);`
>
> Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying
>   the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

And ultimately, [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name, or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML
>   compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element
>   or even transform the DOM element and its children.

Comment: Yeah but that would mean watching one variable for every DOM element I want to keep track of and I still wouldn't have access to the DOM element itself. I may have found a solution involving directives but I'll have to test it first.

Comment: @Bogdan Directives sound like a good plan. "At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children."

Comment: Yep, I'll just broadcast an event from that directive and listen to it in a service. the only problem now is triggering the directive whenever "currentElement" changes...